# Ajax Slim Framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slim

I am working on a ajax to call the slimframework API and post data to the DB. But ajax PUT do not work? I keep getting a 404 in ajax .

**This works**

```
<form action="http://myapi.com/api/key/514315/push" method="post">
<input type="input" name="test" value="test">

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

**Trying in Ajax, this oes not work**  : returns 404 when sending data, as if you accessed API without sending a put request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Data = [
    {
        "Name" : 'Home',
        "Description" : "This is a test description",
        "Keywords" : "Keyword One, Two, Threeh",
        "Menu" : 1,
        "Parent" : 0
    },
    {
        "Name" : 'About',
        "Description" : "This is a About description",
        "Keywords" : "Keyword One, Two, Threeh",
        "Menu" : 2,
        "Parent" : 0
    }

];

var rootURL = "http://myapi.com/api/key/514315/push";

$.each(Data, function(key, value) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "json",
        data: Data[key],
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Article Added');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Add Article error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
$app->post('/key/:key/push', function ($key) {


        $app = new \Slim\Slim();

        $body = $app->request->getBody();

        $singleRequest =  $app->request->params('test');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($body);
        echo "</pre>";

        echo "<hr>";


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($singleRequest);
        echo "</pre>";


});

$app->run();
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: This still shows 404?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
if(array_key_exists('HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS', $_SERVER)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '
           . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']);
} else {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
}

if("OPTIONS" == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    exit(0);
}
```

Added this into PHP